# Find Specific *.exe files in directories and run the app with parameters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

I'm trying to find recursively all "MyApp.exe" apps in "C:\Builds" folder and run the apps with "createdatabase closeimmediately" arguments/parameters.

What I search so far:[ForFiles Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles#BKMK_examples)

Here is the forfiles pattern:

`forfiles [/p <Path>] [/m <SearchMask>] [/s] [/c "<Command>"] [/d [{+|-}]`[{|}]]

Here is what I have:

```
forfiles /p c:\Builds /s /m MyApp.exe /c "cmd /c start @path" "createdatabase closeimmediately"
```

If I run above script, it is showing error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'createdatabase closeimmediately'.Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

If I run without parameteres, it finds apps correctly and runs, but I need to run with parameters:

```
forfiles /p c:\Builds /s /m MyApp.exe /c "cmd /c start @path"
```

**How can I run apps with parameters in ForFiles?**

Comment: You have unbalanced/unnecessary doublequotes; try `"cmd /c start @path createdatabase closeimmediately"`

Comment: @Compo didn't work, it is showing error message: Windows cannot find 'createdatabase'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and try again

Comment: @Jamaxack, the `start` command would need an empty title because `@path` is doublequoted. i.e `"cmd /c start 0x220x22 @path createdatabase closeimmediately"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple methods possible to search for `MyApp.exe` in `C:\Build` and all subfolders and execute the found executable with the two parameters `createdatabase` and `closeimmediately`.

---

The first solution uses command **FOR** to search for any file matching the wildcard pattern `MyApp*.exe` in `C:\Build` and any non-hidden subfolder.

For usage in a batch file:

```
for /R "C:\Build" %%I in ("MyApp*.exe") do if /I "%%~nxI" == "MyApp.exe" "%%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

For usage in command prompt window:

```
for /R "C:\Build" %I in ("MyApp*.exe") do @if /I "%~nxI" == "MyApp.exe" "%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

It is necessary that the string inside the round brackets contains at least one `*` or `?` to define a wildcard pattern. Otherwise **FOR** would not search for files with name `MyApp.exe` on using just `"MyApp.exe"` in `C:\Build` and all its subfolders. It would simply append the string `"MyApp.exe"` (with the double quotes) to folder path of every folder found in `C:\Build` folder structure and would assign folder path + `"MyApp.exe"` to loop variable `I` and execute the command line referencing the loop variable.

The **IF** condition is used to make sure that only `MyApp.exe` is executed and not for example `MyAppOther.exe` found by chance also by **FOR** with wildcard pattern `MyApp*.exe`. The string comparison is done case-insensitive because of `/I`.

It would be also possible to use a different wildcard pattern like `MyApp.exe*`. This could reduce the number of false positives. But for security the **IF** condition should be nevertheless used.

---

The second solution is using just `MyApp.exe` and check if a file with that name really exists in the given folder path before executing it.

For usage in a batch file:

```
for /R "C:\Build" %%I in (MyApp.exe) do if exist "%%I" "%%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

For usage in command prompt window:

```
for /R "C:\Build" %I in (MyApp.exe) do @if exist "%I" "%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

`MyApp.exe` is specified in round brackets without being enclosed in `"` as otherwise the string assigned to loop variable `I` would be for example `C:\Build\"MyApp.exe"` and not `C:\Build\MyApp.exe`. By automatic error correction the string value `C:\Build\"MyApp.exe"` might also work depending on which string is really used instead of `MyApp.exe`. But this is not really a safe method and does not work if the string `MyApp.exe` contains a space, comma, semicolon, or other characters like `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.

---

The third solution is using the command **DIR** for searching for `MyApp.exe` without a wildcard pattern to find only files with exactly that name and let **FOR** execute the found executables with that name.

For usage in a batch file:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Build\MyApp.exe" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do "%%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

For usage in command prompt window:

```
for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir "C:\Build\MyApp.exe" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do @"%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

In comparison to **FOR** the command **DIR** really searches for files with name `MyApp.exe` even on argument string not containing a wildcard character like `*` or `?`.

**FOR** executes the **DIR** command line in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background and captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of this command process.

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

`2>nul` is used to suppress the error message output by **DIR** to handle **STDERR** by redirecting it to device **NUL** if no file `MyApp.exe` could be found in `C:\Build` or its subdirectories.

**DIR** outputs because of `/B` and `/S` just the full qualified file name, i.e. file path + file name + file extension, of every found `MyApp.exe` line by line.

**FOR** processes the captured output line by line with skipping empty lines and lines starting with a semicolon. Such lines are surely not output by **DIR** with the used options.

**FOR** would also split up each line into substrings (tokens) on spaces/tabs and would assign only first substring to loop variable `I`. This string splitting behavior is not wanted here as a folder name could contain one or more spaces. For that reason **FOR** option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of delimiters which disables the line splitting behavior.

---

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`

Answer (score 2):

I know this was mentioned in the comments, but the comments are becoming too long for me to post a decent comment still, so here is an answer. This should do exactly what you want, it will recursively search for the file and execute `if exist`s.

```
@echo off
for /r "c:\Builds" %%i in (myapp.exe) do if exist "%%i" "%%i" createdatabase closeimmediately
```

a slightly different way, find all executables, and launch if the name matches `myapp.exe`:

```
for /r "c:\Builds" %%i in (*.exe) do if /I "%%~nxi" == "myapp.exe" "%%I" createdatabase closeimmediately
```